# How to use loop function to search same file to delete file?

Tags: php, loops, scandir

I have a problem regarding the deletion of two files (both with the same file name) in two diffrent folders. I tried using the unlink function for deletion. How can I delete these two files in these two different folders using PHP unlink function?

Can anyone guide me on how to use array_intersect to find the select file and push those into array and run a foreach loop over that array to delete using unlink?

```html
<?php
$i = 1;
$files = scandir("upload_dms_file/uploads_meeting_document");
$files_2 =scandir("upload_dms_file/uploads_filing_file");

$result=array_intersect($files,$files_2);

// $date = $files[$a];
for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++) {

    ?>

    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $i++; ?></td>
        <td> <a href="upload_dms_file/uploads_meeting_document/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" target="_blank"> <?php echo $files[$a]; ?></a></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a href="upload_dms_file/uploads_meeting_document/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>"
                                                      download="<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                    Download</a></button>
            &nbsp &nbsp
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a
                        href="upload_dms_file/delete_meeting_document.php?name=uploads_meeting_document/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                    Delete
                </a></button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
} ?>
```

Below is my deletion code, it succeeds deleting the file in the uploads_meeting_document folder, so my question is how to delete the other copy of the file located in the uploads_filing_file (variable is $files_2) folder?

```html
<?php
unlink($_GET["name"]);

// Redirecting back
header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
?>
```

Below is my output page:

[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvZS0.png)

Hope someone can guide me how to solve it. I have stucked these problem in the few days. Thanks.

Comment: you can check in both folder if file exists. like `$files = scandir("upload_dms_file/uploads_meeting_document");
$files_2 =scandir("upload_dms_file/uploads_filing_file");
if(in_array($_GET["name"],$files)) { unlink($_GET["name"]);}; if(in_array($_GET["name"],$files_2 )) { unlink($_GET["name"]);};`

Comment: @Deepak Thanks for you comments. Can you using your code to replace my code then rewrite in the below? So that I can mark you if correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make changes in your deletion code like below.

```
<?php
   $folder1 = "uploads_meeting_document";
   $folder2 = "uploads_filing_file";

   $files = scandir($folder1); 
   $files_2 =scandir($folder2); 

   if(in_array($_GET["name"],$files)) { 
        unlink($folder1 . "/" . $_GET["name"]);
   }; 
   if(in_array($_GET["name"],$files_2 )) { 
        unlink($folder2 . "/" . $_GET["name"]);
   };

   // Redirecting back
   header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
?>
```

First get list of all files in both folder then each each folder if given file exist in the folder then unlink. This will delete file from both folder.

Comment: I am using your coding to replace my code, no work. Can't make it delete both files

Comment: Sorry, we need to give full file path with extension to unlink file. Updated the code.

Comment: I am using your updated code, now both files can't delete.

Comment: just noticed you are providing complete path to delete from your form. `href="upload_dms_file/delete_meeting_document.php?name=uploads_meeting_document/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">` please change it to `href="upload_dms_file/delete_meeting_document.php?name=<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">`. I also updated folder path in my answer.

Comment: Same also. Both files can't delete

Comment: Can you try returning some test string from your `delete_meeting_document.php`, like `echo $_GET["name"]; exit;`. To see the response.

Comment: Sorry.Just now you make this change to href="upload_dms_file/delete_meeting_document.php?name=<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;"> can work. I miss the symbol.